# How to find domain extension from 3rd level domain or sub-domain in php

Tags: php, string, pattern-matching

I want to find domain extension from given domains.

```
$domains=array('rni.nic.in','ccert.edu.in', 'xyz.rni.nic.in', 'www.subdomain.gov.in');
```

I needs value from second last domain like .gov.in or .nic.in

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: $allow_domains = array('.gov.in', '.nic.in', '.ac.in', '.edu.in',);

function splitDomain($url) { 
 $host = "";
 $url = parse_url($url);
 print_r($url);
 if(isset($url['host'])) { 
    $host = $url['host'];
 } else {
    $host = $url['path'];
 }
 $host = str_replace('www.','',$host);
 $tmp = explode('.', $host);
 $name = $tmp[0];
 return $tld = $tmp[1];
}
echo $ext = splitDomain('bizdir.gov.in');
$l7 = substr($ext, -7);
$l6 = substr($ext, -6);
if(in_array($l6, $allow_domains) || in_array($l7, $allow_domains)){
   echo ' got it ';
}

Comment: Edit your original post to add any new information or code. There is no way to decipher code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for matching character groups after dots

regex :

```
`/\.(\w+)\.(\w+)$/`
```

and for returning result you can use

```
`preg_match(pattern, subject, match)`
```

You can do something like this:

```
$domains = array('rni.nic.in', 'ccert.edu.in', 'xyz.rni.nic.in', 'www.subdomain.gov.in');

preg_match('/\.(\w+)\.(\w+)$/', 'rni.nic.in', $domain1);

echo $domain1[0];

preg_match('/\.(\w+)\.(\w+)$/', 'www.subdomain.gov.in', $last);

echo $last[0];
```

Refer documentation here :

===> [preg_match docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Hope this do what you want.